# Compactness in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{h_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$. Let $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection to $\operatorname{span}\{h_1,\cdots, h_n\}$.

> **Claim:** A bounded subset $U\subset H$ is relatively compact if and only if $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{x\in U} \|x-P_nx\|=0$$

**Attempt:**

"$\implies$": Let $\epsilon>0$. By assumption, the open cover $\overline{U}\subset\bigcup_{x\in U} B_\epsilon(x)$ has a finite subcover $\overline{U}\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_\epsilon(c_i)$. Then we can choose a certain $N_i\in \Bbb N$ such that $$\|c_i-P_nc_i\|<\epsilon$$ holds for $n\geq N_i$. Now I want to put $N=\max\{N_i:i=1,\cdots, n\}$. Then one has for all $x\in B_\epsilon(c_i)$ and $n\geq N$
$$\|c_i-P_nx\|\leq \|c_i-P_nc_i\|+\|P_nc_i-P_nx\|<2\epsilon$$

Now let $x\in U$ be arbitrary with, say, $x\in B_\epsilon(c_i)$. Then we have $$\|x-P_nx\|\leq \|x-c_i\|+\|c_i-P_nx\|<3\epsilon$$
whenever $n\geq N$. That proves what we've been trying to show.

"$\impliedby$": I let $x=(x_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}\subset U$ be any sequence and I want to find a Cauchy subsequence. For $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $n_\epsilon\in \Bbb N$ with $$\sup_{x\in U}\|x-P_{n_\epsilon}x\|<\epsilon$$

Since $\operatorname{image }P_{n_\epsilon}\subset \Bbb C^{n_\epsilon}$, we can find a Cauchy subsequence of $\left( P_{n\epsilon}x_k \right)_{k\in \Bbb N}$, say $\left( P_{n\epsilon}x_{k_i} \right)_{i\in \Bbb N}$.
Then $(x_{k_i})_{i\in \Bbb N}$ satisfies $$\|x_{k_i}-x_{k_j}\|\leq\|x_{k_i}-P_{n\epsilon}x_{k_i}\|+\|P_{n\epsilon}x_{k_i}-P_{n\epsilon}x_{k_j}\|+\|P_{n\epsilon}x_{k_j}-x_{k_j}\|<3\epsilon$$
for sufficiently large $i,j$.

This does not imply that $(x_{k_i})_{i\in \Bbb N}$ is the Cauchy subsequence we were looking for, because we fixed the $\epsilon>0$ before choosing the subsequence. But it looks somewhat promising regardless. Can we remedy the situation using some "diagonalization-esque" argument?

**Don't feel obliged address my attempt, I may have overcomplicated things.**